# How to backup Debian system to Apple hfsplus Harddisk?

Tags: debian, mount, hfs+

I think the only option is to move a zip file there but I get when trying to create a directory there on `hfsplus` file system at `/media/masi/Elements/`.

```
masi@masi:/media/masi/Elements$ mkdir MasiWeek
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘MasiWeek’: Read-only file system
masi@masi:/media/masi/Elements$
```

`df -T | grep hfs` output

```
/dev/sdb2      hfsplus  4883299280 615565288 4267733992  13% /media/masi/Elements
```

Test command which I would like to run after successful creation of the directory in the disk

```
 nice tar --keep-directory-symlink -czf /media/masi/MasiWeek/backup_home_19.8.2017.tar.gz /home/masi/
```

OS: Debian 9

Comment: You can't. Sorry to say that, but as soon as it's on hfs+, it's no "backup" anymore. Even without considering the problems with the linux hfs driver, backup on hfs(+) is not a good idea. I've been a mac lover for decades, but hfs(+) has always been a pain for me. TimeMachine is a great tool, but every now and then you have to start anew due to some hfs problems. I hope for apfs and pray that I don't need my backup until then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer in Philippos' comment

> You can't. Sorry to say that, but as soon as it's on hfs+, it's no "backup" anymore. Even without considering the problems with the linux hfs driver, backup on hfs(+) is not a good idea. I've been a mac lover for decades, but hfs(+) has always been a pain for me. TimeMachine is a great tool, but every now and then you have to start anew due to some hfs problems. I hope for apfs and pray that I don't need my backup until then.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your HFS+ filesystem is mounted read-only. You could use `force` option (at your own risk) to mount with write access as described in [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/hfsplus.txt) :

> Used to force write access to volumes that are marked as journalled or locked.  Use at your own risk.

To remount already mounted read-only filesystem to read-write:

```
mount -t hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /media/masi/Elements
```

---

**Alternatively** you could disable journaling in OSX, as described in [ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/hfsplus). Afterwards you should be able to mount read-write without `force` option. Same wiki article also notes:

> Disabling journaling on your main OS X partition is not recommended however as journaling is an important feature of any filesystem that can prevent damage and data loss

---

Best option in my opinion is to use device which has more supported filesystem, or backup using some other method (network; NAS, samba, etc).

Comment: It sounds like something can break with the force option. What are other options?

Comment: Other option is to disable journaling or backing up to device with different (more supported) filesystem.